how to style segment in SegmentedButton widget
i need segment to have different color for selected & unselected segments
 SegmentedButton<String>(
                selected: _selectedSegment,
                showSelectedIcon: false,
                multiSelectionEnabled: false,
                segments: [
                  ButtonSegment(
                    value: 'pending',
                    label: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        color: _selectedSegment.contains('pending') ? Color(0xff124549) : Colors.grey[200],
                      ),
                      child: Text('Pending',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: _selectedSegment.contains('pending') ? Colors.white : Color(0xff124549),
                                ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ButtonSegment(
                    value: 'accepted',
                    label: Container(
                      //padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      child: Text('Accepted',style: TextStyle(
                        color: _selectedSegment.contains('accepted')?Colors.white : Color(0xff124549),),),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        color: _selectedSegment.contains('accepted') ? Color(0xff124549) : Colors.grey[200],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                onSelectionChanged: (newselection){
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedSegment = newselection;
                  });
                },
              ),


Try to set style to SegmentedButton like... style: SegmentedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent),

I am not getting Segmented.styleFrom() option, but getting style property

Yes, in style you will find SegmentedButton.styleFrom in which you can style your segment.

Checkout below answer.

you can use style Property in SegmentedButton like this:
SegmentedButton<String>(
style: SegmentedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
              foregroundColor: Colors.red,
              selectedForegroundColor: Colors.white,
              selectedBackgroundColor: Colors.green,
            ),
// You Code
),


Here is a note:
you can use SegmentedButton.styleFrom method for basic interaction like this:
 return SegmentedButton<Settings>(
  style: SegmentedButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
    foregroundColor: Colors.red,
    selectedForegroundColor: Colors.white,
    selectedBackgroundColor: Colors.green,
    side: const BorderSide(
      color: Colors.indigo
    ),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    )
  ),

But you can also use MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith method which allows you to apply styles dynamically based on the button’s current state. This provides far more flexibility and control over styling for different interactions, such as hovering, selecting, or disabling.
 return SegmentedButton<Settings>(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((Set<WidgetState> states) {
      if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
        return Colors.blue; // background when selected
      } else if (states.contains(WidgetState.hovered)) {
        return Colors.grey; // background when hovered
      }
      return Colors.white;  // default background
    }),
    foregroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((Set<WidgetState> states) {
      return states.contains(WidgetState.selected) ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
    }),
  ),
)

I wrote an article on how to customize Segmented Button in Flutter.
Here is my research on this topic on Medium: https://medium.com/@wartelski/mastering-flutters-segmentedbutton-advanced-customization-techniques-8174db1b9f9e
I hope it helps.
